# Angular checkbox change event

Tags: angular

I have written change event for a a condition based on checking of above checkbox  :
(change)="getHighlyLevarageMeasure($event)"
How can I print Boolean value true and false . for checked =true and unchecked =false.

Comment: is this possible through console.log() ? where do you want to "print" it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not very clear let me try to answer it

In .ts file you can write

```
getHighlyLevarageMeasure(data) {
 //  data.checked is true when checkbox is checked else false
 const finalResult = data.checked
 console.log(finalResult)
}
```

If you want to print it in the HTML you can specify the finalResult as global variable and bind it in your html within {{}} tag

**Note:** You can directly use data.checked I used a variable if you want to print on the html side

Hope that helps. If yes please mark it as answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: you neend't a ternary operator, you can simply use `finalResult=data.checked`

Comment: @Eliseo Agree with you. Answer modified